# How to insert a variable in select count

Tags: android, select

I would like to replace the letter `M` with a variable. Once created and managed by the shared preference I enter in the relevant part of the code, replacing `'M'` with `"+ turno_1 +"` but even if the variable is recognized (which I can see from the log), I create a FATAL ERROR.

```
Cursor mcursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(turno) AS mutua FROM "+DbHelper.TURNI+" WHERE MESE = 'Gennaio'and TURNO = 'M' ", null);
```

if I put

```
Cursor mcursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(turno) AS mutua FROM "+DbHelper.TURNI+" WHERE MESE = 'Gennaio'and TURNO = "+turno_1+"", null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`turno_1` doesn't have the quote chars embedded in it.  Either add the quote chars, or use a parameter `" WHERE MESE = 'Gennaio' and TURNO = ?"`, and then provide `turno_1` in a `String` array of args in the next param (where you have `null` now): `new String[]{ turno_1 }`.

Full example:

```
Cursor mcursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(turno) AS mutua FROM "+DbHelper.TURNI+" WHERE MESE = 'Gennaio' and TURNO = ?", new String[]{ turno_1 });
```

Comment: Thank you for having responded to me, but it still does not work,

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {turni.db.tab/com.turniDB.TurniDB}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {turni.db.tab/mesi.Gennaio}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Mutua"

Comment: At my code I tried to enter a numeric value in shared preference, eg 8 instead of Mutual and so it all works, why accept numeric values ​​and not letters